Ошибка С2664, как исправить?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* get_substr(char* sub, char* str);

int main()
{   
    char* substr;
    substr = get_substr("three", "one two three four");
    cout << "substring found: " << substr;

    return 0;

}

char* get_substr(char* sub, char* str) {
    int t;
    char* p, * p2, * start;
    for (t = 0; str[t]; t++) {
        p = &str[t];
        start = p;
        p2 = sub;
        while (*p2 && *p2 == *p) {
            p++;
            p2++;
        }

        if (!*p2)
            return start;
    }
    return 0;
}

Скриншот с VS2022 подсветка и описание ошибок


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. как задать хороший вопрос. 2. как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Хоть и не нравятся мне "товарищи", все же кратко расскажу. Кресты (т.е. С++) это язык с более строгой типизацией, нежели Си. Строковые литералы (это символы в кавычках), которые вы передаете в get_substr() имеют тип const char *, а не char * (и автоматически не приводятся к типу char *, который требует объявление этой функции). Поскольку get_substr() не меняет содержимое своих параметров, вы можете смело объявить их в списке параметров с типом const char *

Не понимаю в чем собственно проблема? Там же написано все четко.
Он подчеркивает 2 аргумента и говорит, что не может сделать неявное преобразование типов и показывает, что есть функция где это происходит.
В комментарии выше все уже сказали, что по умолчания, ваши строки это константные строковые литералы(почитайте что это такое тут).
Чтобы это исправить, вам нужно либо аргументы сделать просто char* или в функции дописать const у ее параметров(если в функции не предусмотрено изменение входных данных).
А так же, вам  стоит почитать про явное и неявное преобразование типов.
